# Django Model instance with variable

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

This is the only way I can get the value I need:

```
 User1.types1.r_q2.label
```

I want to make it dynamic by replacing `field name` and `textChoices` with variable. How can I get it done?

Models.py:

```
class User1(models.Model):

    class r_q1(models.TextChoices):
        r_q2 = 'r_q2', 'second question'
        r_q3 = 'r_q3', 'third question'
        t_greeting = 't_greeting', 't_greeting'
        f_passport = 'f_passport', 'Contact with a human f_passport'


    r_q1 = models.CharField (
        'How can I help you, today?1',
        max_length=200,
        choices=r_q1.choices, blank=True, null=False
    )
```

This works but when I replace only `fieldname`:

```
User1.types1[x].label
```

When I do it for `textChoices` name it doesn't work and raise error:

```
User1[y][x].label
```

error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'ModelBase' object is not subscriptable
```

Sidenote: I have many textChoices in my models.py. I didn't include them as they are not important here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get it to work by using `getattr()`.

```
getattr(User1, 'types1')['r_q2'].label
```

When using variables:

```
y='types1'
x='r_q2'

getattr(User1, y)[x].label
```

There won't be any problem.

Comment: Thank you for coming back and answering once you found a solution.